# HttpPostedFileBase via Angular to Web API always null

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, webapi, httppostedfilebase

I'm trying to upload large files for Azure which I can do via jQuery and standard MVC controller.

However I want to upload via AngularJS to a Web API to perform the upload. I've the Angular form as...

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-app="myAppModule">
    <div ng-controller="myAppController">
            <span>Choose Video</span>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="upload" />
            <input type="submit" ng-click="save()" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller.js is...

```
app.controller('myAppController', function ($scope, myAppService) {
$scope.save = function () {
var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

    var FileUpload = {
        FileName: "Filename Temp",
        Description: "Description Temp",
        File: f
    };

        var promisePost = myAppService.post(UploadFile);
        promisePost.then(function (pl) {
        // do something..
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Err" + err);
        });
    };
});
```

The service.js is...

```
app.service('myAppService', function ($http) {
this.post = function (UploadFile) {
      var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/uploadapi",
        data: UploadFile
    });
    return request;
    }
});
```

My model is...

```
public class UploadFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFile File { get; set; }
}
```

And for testing only my Web Api "post" is...

```
public void Post(UploadFile thePostedFile)
{
    //do something...
}
```

Stepping through I can see the filename, description and file itself via `console.log` right through to the service.js file. The API gets called and I can see filename and description in the UploadModel model, but the HttpPostedFileBase file is always null.

I find this AngularJS method quite clean and compact but I'm stuck on how to get HttpPostedFileBase populated.

Can anyone advise please if/where I'm going wrong?

Comment: you should use header `enctype= multipart/form-data` while posting file

Comment: Where would I add that? Also will that not cause issues with large file uploads e.g. I aim on uploading in excess of 1gb files - the ai calls some code to help upload in blocks, I just need it passing across.

Comment: I don't know it would support 1gb upload or not..but you should add header `headers : { 'enctype' : 'multipart/form-data'}`

Comment: You mean the service.js file e.g. var request = $http({
              method: "post",
              headers : { 'enctype' : 'multipart/form-data'},
              url: "/api/uploadapi",
              data: UploadFile

Comment: I mean `this.post = function (UploadFile) {
      var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/uploadapi",
headers : { 'enctype' : 'multipart/form-data'}
        data: UploadFile
    });
    return request;
    }
});`

Comment: That still passes though as null I'm afraid... :(

Comment: Paul Deehan, have you got any solution? I am also facing the same issue, but could not find any solution.

Comment: I decided to use a different method in the end as the AngularJs approach was not mandatory - what I did is loosely based on the following: http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2013/07/01/upload-file-to-windows-azure-blob-in-chunks-through-asp.net.aspx